# SplitViewController updating detail view

Tags: iphone, uisplitviewcontroller, ipad

I'm using a SplitViewController, and I want to extend how it's being used but I've got stucked with this stuff...

I want to achieve something like this:

1. In my master controller of splitview (mainCategory), if the cell is selected, I've pushed another controller (subCategory), then, update also the detail controller of the splitView (2nd detail view) --> I've done this already..
2. When the master controller of splitView is the pushed controller (subCategory for this example), then I've select the "back" button of the navigation, I need to update also the detail controller of the splitView to 1st detail view…. but how ??? I'm stucked with this problem...?

Any help pls?? I'm already followed the apple sample code MultipleDetailView but my case is different.. appreciate any help/advise.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The following code should fix your issue.

```
[detailViewController.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];

[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

[Example Project to examine can be downloaded here.](http://www.mediafire.com/?49yb2n49cky9tzy)

[Example obtained from this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5263128/splitviewcontroller-with-two-navigationcontroller-linking-protocols](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5263128/splitviewcontroller-with-two-navigationcontroller-linking-protocols)

Answer (score 0):

Building the Example Project in Xcode 3.24 with the iOS 4.0 SDK gets 7 warnings re. MainWindow.xib: six about missing outlets in the app delegate and view controller classes, one about a missing action method.

Running the built app in the iPad Simulator gets a crash as the .xib file is being loaded.

Sure enough, looking at the code I can see the objects the outlets refer to ARE missing from the class declarations (while their '@property' and '@synthesize' declarations are present as expected). But adding the missing code doesn't make the warnings go away. And running the "fixed" code gets the exact same crash.

I also made the changes referenced by the second link in Unixed's post. No change in the warnings on build or the crash on run.